# sql slow performance with function

Tags: sql, oracle

I  have following function:

```
Create function code_status
( p_code varchar, p_daytime date);

Select status into l_value from table1 where code=p_code and daytime=p_daytime;

Return l_value;

End;
```

And I use it in sql query below:

```
Select code, daytime, code_status(code, daytime) from table2
where daytime = '12 Jan 2017'
```

Query with this function runs very slow, is there any way to improve it, I dont think I need function here?

Thanks

Comment: you don't need the function, just join the tables

Comment: If a query runs slow, get an execution plan.

Comment: Tbone, can you give example of join for this case? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function really isn't needed.  It basically pulls from a lookup table (table1) to get a single value (status).  So, join to it instead to get status, something like:

```
Select t2.code, t2.daytime, t1.status 
from table2 t2
left join table1 t1 on (t1.code=t2.code and t1.daytime=t2.daytime)
where t2.daytime = to_date('12 Jan 2017', 'DD Mon YYYY');
```

where table1 is your lookup table for status, and table2 is the driving table.

Comment: Thanks tbone, I'll test it.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
Select status into l_value
from table1
where code = p_code and daytime = p_daytime;
```

You want an index.  The best index is `table1(code, daytime, status)`.

Comment: Not sure I can index table1 since its applcation table and we cant change it.